# Why does tmux new-session propagate the value of PATH to the new session?

Tags: environment-variables, tmux

When running `tmux new-session`, a new tmux session is created, and depending on whether a server exists or not, the following happens:

- if there's no server running, a new one gets created, and the session inherits the whole environment because it ends up in the global server environment
- if there's already a server running, the session inherits the global environment of the server, plus a list of specific overrides that are set from the environment of the shell that called the `tmux new-session` command

The list of specific overrides for the second case can be defined using the `update-environment` option, which defaults to `["DISPLAY", "KRB5CCNAME", "SSH_ASKPASS", "SSH_AUTH_SOCK", "SSH_AGENT_PID", "SSH_CONNECTION", "WINDOWID", "XAUTHORITY"]`

However, it seems that `PATH` is an exception, as it doesn't appear in the list above, but nevertheless gets propagated into the new session.

What's the reason of this behavior?

What I tried is `export PATH=$PATH:/hello FOO=bar` and then  `tmux new-session`: the session had `PATH` containing `:/hello` at the end, but `FOO` wasn't set. The expected behavior would have been to have `PATH` set as the same value of the tmux global environment (which can be printed with `tmux show-environment -g`), rather than having the local override `:/hello`. `FOO` was not set, and that was the expected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to comments in [source code](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/b55f34029ac05474dfd993c187b9c61bbcd4e1a1/spawn.c) the behavior is intentional:

```c
    /*
     * Then the PATH environment variable. The session one is replaced from
     * the client if there is one because otherwise running "tmux new
     * myprogram" wouldn't work if myprogram isn't in the session's path.
     */
    if (c != NULL && c->session == NULL) { /* only unattached clients */
        ee = environ_find(c->environ, "PATH");
        if (ee != NULL)
            environ_set(child, "PATH", 0, "%s", ee->value);
    }
    if (environ_find(child, "PATH") == NULL)
        environ_set(child, "PATH", 0, "%s", _PATH_DEFPATH);
```

It makes sense to me since `PATH` is so essential and many other programs depend on it to work properly. If you need to pass other env vars you can use `new-session -e FOO=bar ..`.